# While entering text in UITextField placeholder should disappear one letter at at time

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, placeholder

I have created a `UITextfield` where i want to add 4 digit password, but once I enter the first digit whole placeholder disappear. how can I keep next three placeholder letters in `UITextfield` while entering next password letters.

here is my screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to try SeanLintern88's solution because it sounded like a little challange. And it is in the case where the text field should have spaces between the underscore.

```
textField.text = "_ _ _ _"
```

This is the solution I came with and while it was fun to write, this is something I do not recommend using in real projects. Better try the 4 separate text fields approach :)

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        guard let text = textField.text else { return false }

        var location = range.location

        //is deleting
        if string == "" {

            guard let indexToReplace = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: location, limitedBy: text.endIndex) else {
                return false
            }

            let isCharDeleted = location % 2 == 0
            //place " " or "_" depending on the position that was deleted
            let stringToReplaceWith = isCharDeleted ? "_" : " "
            let charachter = stringToReplaceWith[stringToReplaceWith.startIndex]
            textField.text?.remove(at: indexToReplace)
            textField.text?.insert(charachter, at: indexToReplace)

            var newCursorPositionOffset = location

            //deletetion occured on space " "
            if !isCharDeleted {

                guard let previousIndex = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: location-1, limitedBy: text.endIndex) else {
                    return false
                }
                //delete the previous charachter
                textField.text?.remove(at: previousIndex)
                let dash = "_"
                let char = dash[dash.startIndex]

                textField.text?.insert(char, at: previousIndex)

                //correct cursor position
                newCursorPositionOffset -= 1
            }

            //move cursor position
            let newPosition = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: newCursorPositionOffset)
            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: newPosition!, to: newPosition!)

            return false
        }

        //is typing
        if range.location + 1 <= text.characters.count,
            let end = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: location+1, limitedBy: text.endIndex),
            let start = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: location, limitedBy: text.endIndex) {
            textField.text = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: string, options: .caseInsensitive, range: Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: start, upper: end)))

            //correct the cursor position if placed on " " index
            if range.location % 2 != 0 {
                location -= 1
            }
        }

        //skip " " and move cursor to the next "_"
        if location+2 < text.characters.count {
            let newPosition = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: location+2)
            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: newPosition!, to: newPosition!)

        }

        return false
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let newPosition = textField.beginningOfDocument
        textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)


    }
}
```

PS: Probably it can be made shorter with better choosing of functions for string operations, but still a pretty .. unfriendly solution.

Conclusion: DON'T DO THIS AT HOME :D

Comment: Thanks for your solution.It did work but it's too long.  can i make it little short?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `placeHolder`, just override the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method and append the characters to the string until the string is 4 characters long, you can also use attributed string if you want the `_` to look different to the dots.

Comment: Tried by replacing placeholder by 'textField.text'. but it's not working. I want to replace those 4 ' _' with text coming from keyboard. is it possible?

Comment: I think its probably best to make a custom solution with 4 text fields

Comment: Multiple text fields may be easier in some ways, but not necessary. All you should need to do is keep track of an attributed string for the passcode, then replace the characters as their typed.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

This is a modified version of @Denislava Shentova's answer that I believe simplifies into less lines of code, fixes issues, and makes the code more readable.

**Not Fully Tested**

```
import UIKit

class YourClass: UIViewController {

    //It is also a good idea to deny users the ability to paste into this textField.

    //set up textField
    let textField : UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        // These are 'long dashes' you can replace them with whatever you would like.
        // These look best IMO.
        textField.text = "——————" //No spaces needed!
        textField.textColor = .black
        textField.textAlignment = .center
        textField.tintColor = .clear //this will hide the cursor.

        return textField
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self
        //This sets the spacing or 'Kern' of the textfield. Adjust the value: 10.0 and the fontSize to get the desired output.
        textField.defaultTextAttributes.updateValue(10.0, forKey: NSAttributedStringKey.kern.rawValue)
    }
}
extension YourClass : UITextFieldDelegate {
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        //get the current text of the textField.
        guard let text = textField.text else { return false }

        //handle backspace event.
        if string == "" {
            guard let indexToReplace = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location, limitedBy: text.endIndex) else { return false }
            textField.text?.remove(at: indexToReplace)
            textField.text?.insert("—", at: indexToReplace)
            //adjust cursor position
            if let newPostion = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: range.location) {
                textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: newPostion, to: newPostion)
                return false
            }
        }
        //handle character entered event.
        if range.location + 1 <= text.count,
            let end = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location + 1, limitedBy: text.endIndex),
            let start = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location, limitedBy: text.endIndex) {
            textField.text = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "—", with: string, options: .caseInsensitive, range: Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: start, upper: end)))
        }
        //adjust cursor position.
        if range.location + 1 < text.count {
            if let newPosition = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: range.location + 1){
                textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    //make sure to start at the begining of the textField.
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let newPosition = textField.beginningOfDocument
        textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
    }
}
```